# How to get deep nesting in lists

Tags: lists

Is there a way to get more than 4 levels of nesting in a list environment?

I'm looking for

```
I.
 A.
  1.
   a.
    (i)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the `enumitem` way to do this, with `\newlist{...}{enumerate}{5}` 
and using specific `\setlist` commands for the various levels:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{5}  % Specify 5 Levels as clone of enumerate
\setlist[mylist,1]{label={\Roman*.}}  % Roman uppercase numbers I.
\setlist[mylist,2]{label={\Alph*.}}   % Latin uppercase letters A.
\setlist[mylist,3]{label={\arabic*.}} % arabic numbers 1.
\setlist[mylist,4]{label={\alph*.}}   % Latin lowercase letters a.
\setlist[mylist,5]{label={(\roman*)}} % roman lowercase letters in ()

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
\item Level 1
\begin{mylist}
  \item Level 2
\begin{mylist}
  \item Level 3
\begin{mylist}
  \item Level 4
\begin{mylist}
  \item Level 5
\end{mylist}    
\end{mylist}   
\end{mylist}    
\end{mylist}
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Personally, I won't use a 5 level - list

Comment: This is the canonical outline labeling that I learned in primary school, and I still find it useful.

Comment: @DeliaRuby: Yes, but it's typographically doubtful ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Have found an answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{longenum}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[longenum,1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setlist[longenum,2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setlist[longenum,3]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[longenum,4]{label=\alph*.}
\setlist[longenum,5]{label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}

\section*{Enumerated list with 5 levels}

\begin{longenum}
  \item Level 1 first
  \item Level 1 second
  \begin{longenum}
    \item Level 2 first
    \item Level 2 second
    \begin{longenum}
      \item Level 3 first
      \item Level 3 second
      \begin{longenum}
        \item Level 4 first
        \item Level 4 second
        \begin{longenum}
          \item Level 5 first
          \item Level 5 second
        \end{longenum}
      \end{longenum}
    \end{longenum}
  \end{longenum}
\end{longenum}

\end{document}
```

Source: http://texblog.org/2011/10/10/increase-enumerate-itemize-depth-with-enumitem/